# How to make underbrace label text wrap at brace width?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, labels, width, wrap

Is there a way to make underbrace label text automatically wrap at the underbraces width, preferably even with automatic syllabication?

Example where brace label text exceeds underbrace width:

```
$\underbrace{f(x) = a^2 + 2ab + b^2}_\text{This is some pretty long label for a rather short formula}$
```

Comment: You'll have to do that manually by setting a fixed width...

Comment: @Werner -- It doesn't have to be completely manual: see my answer ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to change the behaviour of `\underbrace` globally you could say

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\let\ams@underbrace=\underbrace
\def\underbrace#1_#2{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{$\displaystyle#1$}%
  \ams@underbrace{#1}_{\parbox[t]{\the\wd0}{#2}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$\underbrace{f(x) = a^2 + 2ab + b^2}_{This is some pretty long label for a rather short formula}$
\end{document}
```

Anyways, you can also create your custom underbrace-macro by using the same argument parsing and nearly the same replacement (in this case there is no need to store the original macro first) -- i.e. `\def\myunderbrace#1_#2{\setbox...\underbrace...}` -- to limit the impact of this hack to where you want it to actually happen.

Now, The output can be imrpoved by adding a different alignment inside the parbox (Thanks to @barbarabeeton!), i.e.

```
...\parbox[t]{\the\wd0}{\centering#2}...% or
%  \parbox[t]{\the\wd0}{\raggedright#2}
```

which yields the following result:

---

[image: output1]

<sub>(First case)</sub>

[image: output2]

<sub>(Second case)</sub>

---

To be more flexible you could then add an optional argument to the `\underbrace` command that specifies the alignment of the underbrace label as `\underbrace[c]{Some maths}_{Some text}`, for instance. The code below allows the following alignment specifications:

- *c* -- centered
- *l* -- left
- *r* -- right
- *f* -- fuzzy

#### Complete Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\let\ams@underbrace=\underbrace
\def\underbrace{\kernel@ifnextchar[{\underbrace@}{\underbrace@[l]}}% default value: l
\def\underbrace@[#1]#2_#3{%
  \ifx#1c\relax
    \let\ubr@align\centering%
  \else
    \ifx#1l\relax
      \let\ubr@align\raggedright%
    \else
      \ifx#1r\relax
        \let\ubr@align\raggedleft%
      \else
        \ifx#1f\relax
          \let\ubr@align\relax%
        \else
          \message{`#1' isn't a valid alignment specification for the underbrace command}%
        \fi
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
  \setbox0=\hbox{$\displaystyle#2$}%
  \ams@underbrace{#2}_{\parbox[t]{\the\wd0}{\ubr@align#3}}%
}
\let\ubr@align\relax
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$\underbrace[c]{f(x) = a^2 + 2ab + b^2}_{This is some pretty long label for a rather short formula}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: The next step would be to wrap that process into the original `\underbrace` macro. But, for that I need latex to `\show` me the original definition in the ams package bundle. Stay tuned... (Maybe I can't make it today as I expect a visitor tonight.)

Comment: Thanks for the quick quick fix. This solution already works for me (when I apply manuall syllabication). Staying tuned for your improved answer. Maybe someone also comes up with a suggestion on how to enable syllabication inside math mode. Working with a german text here where the longer words tend to destroy the blockset layout, example: \setbox0=\hbox{$\displaystyle\mathcal{P}(Q \times \Gamma \times \lbrace L,R \rbrace)$}
$\underbrace{\mathcal{P}(Q \times \Gamma \times \lbrace L,R \rbrace)}_\text{\parbox{\the\wd0}{Potenzmenge von Folgezuständen Wahlmöglichkeiten}}$

Comment: spacing would look better if `\centering` or `\raggedright` were used in the `\parbox`

Comment: @norritt -- Your other example looks ok to me with the alternative alignment inside the parbox. What do you think?

Comment: Hey Ruben, yes the macro you wrote works like a charm - also for the alternative example, thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 11):

In this code I define a `\parunderbrace` command, with two arguments, which adjusts automatically to the width of the formula:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newlength\ubwidth
\newcommand\parunderbrace[2]{\settowidth\ubwidth{$#1$}\underbrace{#1}_{\parbox{\ubwidth}{\scriptsize\RaggedRight#2}}}

\begin{document}

\[ \parunderbrace{f(x) = a^2 + 2ab + b^2}{This is some pretty long label for a rather short formula} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]